# Is there an easy way to make a blocky insert cursor for the Tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

The `insert cursor` of the `Text` widget doesn't seem to have a lot of options (just width, border, and blinking). To replicate a command-line style blocky or underscore-type cursor, I tried to start by changing the `insertwidth` option, but it looks like instead of expanding the width to the right, as I hoped, it expands out from the center of the cursor:

```
root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

text.insert('1.0', 'hello world')

text.config(insertwidth=40)

mainloop()
```

[image: insertwidth=40]

Is there something simple I'm missing, or is this functionality going to be more complex than changing an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, maybe I just made too much work for myself and there's a really simple way to do this that I haven't found, but here's the solution I made to handle this, in case anyone else needs to do the same type of thing:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Text
from tkFont import Font


class BlockyCursorText(Text):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Text.__init__(self, parent, bg='black', fg='green', insertwidth=0,
                      font=Font(family='Courier', size=10))

        # initialize the cursor position and the color of the cursor
        self.cursor = '1.0'
        self.switch = 'green'

        self._blink_cursor()
        self._place_cursor()


    def _place_cursor(self):
        '''check the position of the cursor against the last known position
        every 15ms and update the cursorblock tag as needed'''

        current_index = self.index('insert')

        if self.cursor != current_index:  # if the insertcursor moved
            self.cursor = current_index   # store the new index
            self.tag_delete('cursorblock')# delete the cursorblock tag

            start = self.index('insert')  # get the start
            end = self.index('insert+1c') # and stop indices

            if start[0] != end[0]:         # this handles an index that
                self.insert(start, ' ')    # reaches the end of the line
                end = self.index('insert') # by inserting a space

            self.tag_add('cursorblock', start, end) # add the tag back in
            self.mark_set('insert', self.cursor)    # move the insertcursor

        self.after(15, self._place_cursor)

    def _blink_cursor(self):
        '''alternate the background color of the cursorblock tagged text
        every 600 milliseconds'''

        if self.switch == 'green':
            self.switch = 'black'
        else:
            self.switch = 'green'

        self.tag_config('cursorblock', background=self.switch)

        self.after(600, self._blink_cursor)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()

    text = BlockyCursorText(root)
    text.pack()
    text.insert('1.0', 'hello world')

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set the [`-blockcursor`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm#M7) option to `True`:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root, blockcursor=True)
# which is equivalent to:
# text['blockcursor'] = True or root.tk.call(text, 'configure', '-blockcursor', True)
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and found much easier solution [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html)

And this is the code from my own project:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(background = '#343833')
root.resizable(False, False)

listlabel = Label(root, height = 30, width = 60, bd=5, relief="sunken", bg = "#343833")
listlabel.pack()

inputentry = Entry(root, bg = "#343833", bd = 5, fg = "#00ff00", width = 60)
inputentry.configure(insertbackground = "#00ff00")
inputentry.configure(highlightthickness = 0)
inputentry.configure(insertwidth = 5)
inputentry.pack()

name = Label(root, bg = "#343833", text = "\nBASIC interpreter\n")
name.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So we may simply say

```
entryObject.configure(insertwidth = <int value>)
```