# How to control the insert cursor in a perl Tk::Text widget?

Tags: perl

I am writing a text editor and wish to flag the user that the "insert" key was pressed.

I am looking for a way to manipulate the "insert cursor" (usually a blinking `|` char) indicating the drawing position of the next clicked-char.

e.g.,

When in "insert" mode: the cursor will be a blinking pipe (`|`)

When in "override" mode (user clicked the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>INS</kbd>): the cursor will be blinking underscore (`_`)

While searching the web, i came across a of examples to manipulate the mouse cursor, but none about manipulating the insert cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to change the cursor image using `configure` on the text widget. But the background shape of the cursor could be changed. For example, when insert mode is active the cursor can be red, and when insert mode is off, the cursor can be black:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = new MainWindow; 

my $text = $mw->Text(qw/-width 40 -height 10/)->pack;
my $current_color = "black";
$text->configure(-insertbackground => $current_color);
$text->configure(-cursor => "arrow");
my $button = $mw->Button(-text => "Quit", -command => sub { exit })->pack;
$text->bind('<Insert>', \&change_cursor );
MainLoop;

sub change_cursor {
    $current_color = $current_color eq "black" ? "red" : "black";
    $text->configure(-insertbackground => $current_color);
}
```

Comment: A workaround seems to be to use tags, see: [Is there an easy way to make a blocky insert cursor for the Tkinter Text widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290393/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-a-blocky-insert-cursor-for-the-tkinter-text-widget)

Comment: While this is an interesting approach, it is barely seen by the user (it just change the insert cursor "|" color)