# How to correctly display cursor in an entry while changing its width?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working on sinclair basic interpreter's GUI with python's Tkinter library. I'm using `inputentry.configure(insertwidth = 7)`to adjust the widht of the blinking cursor.

Currently it works more or less fine but I want my cursor to be slightly wider, like in linux terminal. The problem is when I set insertwidth up to 10 or 15 it starts to overlap nearby characters. The below code draws an entry so you can see directly what is wrong:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

inputentry = Entry(root)
inputentry.configure(insertwidth = 15)
inputentry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

did anyone face such sort of problem? How can I achieve linux-like cursor behaviour in a graphical(non-console) interface with Tkinter library? Any help would be gratly appriciated.

Comment: For the sake of this question, you can remove the vast majority of the code in your question. All we really need is the entry widget and enough code to make it work. See [mcve]

Comment: Thank you, Bryan, I've changed code accordingly to you instructions. This is my very first question on Stack Overflow so I'm sorry for the tons of unnecessary code)

Comment: It'd be [easier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47246083/6634373) to switch to one-line `Text` widget , since it has an [option](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm#M7) for such behavior.

Comment: What a fantastic solution! Thank's a lot, CommonSense. It works perfectly and this is the exact behaviour I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `Tkinter.Entry()` widget, the behavior you are trying to achieve is **not** feasible.

The suitable way to modify the cursor's position is by using [`icursor(index)`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) method which *sets the insertion cursor just before the character at the given index*. So when using:

```
inputentry.configure(insertwidth = "10")
```

It is useless to try to run something like this:

```
inputentry.icursor(inputentry.index(END)+5) #insertwidth/2 = 5
```

Because we can not push the cursor *farther* than `tk.END` or *closer* than 0.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, Billal, I've realized myself what you've just explained a couple of hours ago. I end up following @CommonSense adwise to switch to one-line Text widget , since it has an option for such behavior because this is the exact result I expected to have