# Horizontal insertion cursor on a tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

Me and my friend are making something similar to a command prompt on Python using tkinter, but we're struggling to replicate the horizontal insertion cursor [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHN0q.png)

We're using an text widget in order to try and do this, and we've got this

`cmdline=Text(command_prompt, bg='black', font = ('Consolas', 11), fg ='white', borderwidth = 0, insertbackground = 'white', insertwidth = '0.75c')`

However it's not quite what we're looking for. Is there any way we can get the insertion cursor at least somewhat similar to the one shown above?
Thank you :)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24329972)